# XML-XSLT Avoid Duplicate then combine

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble to stop the XSLT transformation when there's already an ID transform for it. I already have the idea how to combine the missing piece once transformation avoid to be duplicated.

Any help will really appreciated, thanks!

MY XML FILE

```
   ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <data>
        <id>1</id>
        <fname>Vcut</fname>
        <lname>Piatos</lname>
        <age>0</age>
        <code>1002</code>
        <hobby>dota</hobby>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>1</id>
        <fname>Mayo</fname>
        <lname>Naise</lname>
        <age>22</age>
        <code>1003</code>
        <hobby>program</hobby>
    </data>
 <data>
        <id>2</id>
        <fname>Ben</fname>
        <lname>Ten</lname>
        <age>22</age>
        <code>1003</code>
        <hobby>Eat</hobby>
    </data>
</row>
```

XSLT TRANSLATION

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

 <xsl:for-each select="row/data">
<EmployeeID>
<xsl:for-each-group select="id" group-by="id">
 <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
    </EmployeeID>
         <EmployeeName>
         <xsl:value-of select='concat(fname," ",lname)' />
        </EmployeeName>
      <EmployeeAge>
            <xsl:value-of select='age'/>
    </EmployeeAge>
      <EmployeeCode><xsl:value-of select="code"/></EmployeeCode>
      <EmployeeActivity><xsl:value-of select="hobby"/></EmployeeActivity>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
<EmployeeName>Vcut Piatos</EmployeeName>
<EmployeeAge>0</EmployeeAge>
<EmployeeCode>1002</EmployeeCode>
<EmployeeActivity>dota</EmployeeActivity>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
<EmployeeID/>
<EmployeeName>Mayo Naise</EmployeeName>
<EmployeeAge>22</EmployeeAge>
<EmployeeCode>1003</EmployeeCode>
<EmployeeActivity>program</EmployeeActivity>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
<EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
<EmployeeName>Ben Ten</EmployeeName>
<EmployeeAge>22</EmployeeAge>
<EmployeeCode>1003</EmployeeCode>
<EmployeeActivity>Eat</EmployeeActivity>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
<EmployeeName>Vcut Piatos</EmployeeName>
<EmployeeAge>0</EmployeeAge>
<EmployeeCode>1002</EmployeeCode>
<EmployeeActivity>dota</EmployeeActivity>
<EmployeeActivity>program</EmployeeActivity>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
<EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
<EmployeeName>Ben Ten</EmployeeName>
<EmployeeAge>22</EmployeeAge>
<EmployeeCode>1003</EmployeeCode>
<EmployeeActivity>Eat</EmployeeActivity>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The output you claim is not the output received when using your code: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVN There are no `EmployeeID` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group `data` by `id`, not `id` by `id` - and you need to do this from the context of `row`, not from the context of `data`:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/row">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="data" group-by="id">
        <EmployeeID>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </EmployeeID>
        <EmployeeName>
            <xsl:value-of select='concat(fname," ",lname)' />
        </EmployeeName>
        <EmployeeAge>
            <xsl:value-of select='age'/>
        </EmployeeAge>
        <EmployeeCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
        </EmployeeCode>
        <EmployeeActivity>
            <xsl:value-of select="hobby"/>
        </EmployeeActivity>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. The result is not well-formed XML, as it has no single root element;
2. The text separator may be helpful for the human reader, but may prove an obstacle for further processing - consider using a comment instead;
3. The result obtained is different from what you posted: the first employee's activity is `data`, not `program`.

Comment: Apologies, comment is not showing in the transform data's. You nailed it perfectly this is my desired output I'll take care of the other conditions. Thanks a lot for the help.